# random.choice(dict.keys())) works when two functions are combined, but when ran separately .keys causes an error

Tags: python, dictionary, random

```
def makeDict(text : str, k : int) -> Dict[str,List[str]]:    
    i = 0
    Dict = {}
    while i < len(text):
        if (i+k) < len(text):
            # the following if statement is used to determine if the k-long characters are already in the dictionary
            if (text[i:i+k] in Dict):
                Dict[text[i:i+k]] = Dict[text[i:i+k]] + text[i+k]
            elif (text[i:i+k] not in Dict): # this will ensure that every set of k characters is added to the dictionary
                Dict[text[i:i+k]] = text[i+k]
        elif (i+k) >= len(text): # this will stop the "string out of range" error
            pass
        i += 1
        
    print(Dict)
    
def randomWriter(tex : str, k : int, outputLen : int) -> str:

    #makeDict(text,k)

    newStr = ""
    rChoice = r.choice(list(Dict.keys()))
    newStr = newStr + rChoice

    x = 0
    while x < len(text):
        #print(newStr) # delete this later, used to track progression
        CharSet = newStr[x:x+k] # used to gather the last k characters in the new string
        if (CharSet in Dict):
            rChoice = r.choice(Dict[str(CharSet)]) # determines next character based off the last ones in the new string
        else:
            rChoice = r.choice(list(Dict.keys()))
            rChoice = " " + rChoice
        newStr = newStr + rChoice
        x += 1
    return newStr
```

The above code takes a string, creates a dictionary, and then randomly generates a new string based on the dictionary. My problem is that when I have the two functions combined (with all the code in makeDict()) it works perfectly fine, but when separated into two functions (as shown above) I get `TypeError: descriptor 'keys' of 'dict' object needs an argument`
I just need help understanding why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: How is `randomwriter()` supposed to access `Dict`?  It's not a parameter, and `makedict()` didn't return it, or store it in a global variable.

Comment: @jasonharper I cannot believe I didn't catch that. Thank you for pointing it out.